# Hide back button on more button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have more than 5 tabbarcontroller. I need to hide the back button from more tabbar. I hidden the more title from this code. How to hide back button?

```
[[ [tabBarController moreNavigationController] visibleViewController]setTitle:@" "];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
   [[[tabBarController moreNavigationController] visibleViewController]navigationItem].hidesBackButton = YES;
```